# Printing values from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that looks like this (the full list is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/jgDbA/1/)):

```
var verbMap = [
    {
        infinitive: "gehen",
        thirdPres: "geht",
        thirdPast: "ging",
        aux: "ist",
        pastPart: "gegangen",
        english: "go"
    },
    {
        infinitive: "gelingen",
        thirdPres: "gelingt",
        thirdPast: "gelang",
        aux: "ist",
        pastPart: "gelungen",
        english: "succeed"
    }
];
```

I am trying to run through each part and print it into a table. I can access one of the values if I target it specifically, but I need to be able to print all of the values into `<td>`s. Each part of the array would be a `<tr>` with the values inside as the `<td>` tags.

What would be the best way to do this, and is there a better way to set the data up and interact with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be too hard to create the table using nested for loops <strike>(the example uses jQuery to build the elements...but you obviously don't have to)</strike>:

**Edit**

Removed the jQuery since it seemed to bother everybody (even though the control structures were the important part of the example):

```
var table = document.createElement('table');

for(v in verbMap){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(p in verbMap[v]){
         var td = document.createElement('td');
         var text = document.createTextNode(verbMap[v][p]);
         td.appendChild(text);
         tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: This requires jQuery but the question does not have the jQuery tag.

Comment: @Peter Olson - I address that in the post. The example is meant to show the looping used, not exactly how to build the elements.

Comment: jQuery wasn't requested or indicated in any way.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock `innerText` is non-standard and unsupported by Firefox.  See my answer if you need that browser.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < verbMath.length; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr'); 
  var item = verbMath[i];
  for (var prop in item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      var data = document.createElement('td');
      data.innerText = item[prop];
      row.appendChild(data);
    }
  }

  // Need to append the row here to the appropriate place in your DOM
}
```

Comment: +1 for using plain javascript (since jQuery wasn't requested or indicated) and for including the use of hasOwnProperty().

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't support `innerText` so it's better to create a text node and add that to the child.  It may also be better to define an array to guarantee an order of the columns and easily change it if necessary.

```
var table = document.getElementById("tbl"), i, j, tr, td, text;

var order = ["infinitive", "thirdPres", "thirdPast", "aux", "pastPart", "english"]

for(i=0; i<verbMap.length; i++){
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(j = 0; j<order.length; j++){
         td = document.createElement('td');
         text = document.createTextNode(verbMap[i][order[j]]);
         td.appendChild(text);
         tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YW2LM/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just using this as a simple study guide though, mainly for myself, so cross-browser compatibility isn't a concern. This will be helpful if I ever need to use this in the future though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some very good tools for creating tables from such data structures. Consider using jQuery and the Datatables plug in.

Here are some links:

jQuery: http://jquery.com/

Datatables: http://datatables.net/

Comment: I tried using jQuery, but I wasn't sure how to go around doing it.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock, yeah, it might seem like you're getting a whole toolbox when you just want to drive a simple nail, but if you'll take a little time with it, you'll soon be able to not only find the hammer, but also enjoy doing things faster with the whole set of tools.

Comment: I know a decent amount of it, but for more complex problems like this I am lost.